# Can't send individual emails from contact record

Tags: wordpress, civimail

When trying to send an email from an individuals Contact Record I am getting a pop-up with the following error listed.

[image: error meassage]

I can send bulk emails to a test group and when I test the outbound email settings the system is sending me an email saying the settings are correct.  I have searched for an answer to this issue but can't find anything related to the error message.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2220 - we never figured out why on some sites it doesn't load the defaults. But you can manually set it with e.g.

`cv ev "Civi::settings()->set('simple_mail_limit', 50);"`

Comment: Thanks for this information.  It's all working now   Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this helped a lot! I exchanged this line in EmailTrait.php on line 361. Best, Michael